# Differentiating internal vs external method call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

There is an object `obj` which has several methods:

```
const obj = {
 a() {}

 b() { this.a() }

 c() { this.a(); }

}
```

And as you can see, internally the methods call each other. `a` is getting called from `b`.

But I can also call `a` from outside like `obj.a()`.

I want to differentiate internal call from outside call.

More context around the requirement:
This object is exposed in JS library which is used by websites as 3rd party library. We want to limit the methods exposed publicly on this object and so we want to know which ones are being called directly by websites currently so that we don't accidentally break them.

One trivial solution is adding an extra flag parameter to all methods and pass that parameter as `true` when calling internally. When called externally, the parameter would stay undefined. But this requires patching all methods and their invocation points. Ideally, I need a solution which works without patching all methods.

Comment: It's a terrible idea to differentiate *how* a method is called. There are many different ways to call methods for a variety of reasons, and you shouldn't change behaviour based on that. Functions should act on their parameters and the object's state only.

Comment: "*I wanna differentiate internal call from outside call.*" sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Or just bad design.

Comment: After your added context: the solution is simple: keep the entire object private, and expose some public object which mimics the API, and calls the internal object, and also logs each call, or whatever you want to do. I.e., add an additional layer around it. You can either write an additional object for that purpose, or wrap your object in a Proxy which intercepts each method call automatically.

Comment: @VLAZ I wont call it an XY problem  I have edited to explain the core problem here.

Comment: `This object is exposed in JS library which is used by websites as 3rd party library. We want to limit the methods exposed publicly…` a common approach is to go through your library and decide which functions have to become private without caring about 3rd party libraries. And then provide these functions that will become private as a deprecated fallback function. Those deprecated functions could log that they are deprecated on their first call with an info what the alternative is.

Comment: @KushagraGour it is still an XY problem. You want to clean up your API to change the functions that should be used. And your idea is one way to to target that problem. So it is an XY problem.

Answer (score 2):

That does not directly answer your question but shows a common way how it is done in other libraries.

One thing that is commonly done is to have a version scheme:
Don't introduce breaking changes in patch (`1.0.x`) or minor (`1.x`) versions and only do breaking changes in major versions.

Now if a function should not be used anymore in your opinion mark it in some way as deprecated.

A way how you could fo that is to have something like this:

```
const obj = {
 // prefix the private function, or choose another way to make clear it is private
 // or that it can't be called publicly
 _private_A() {
 
 },
 a() {
   console.warn("`a` is deprecated use … instead. This function will be removed in version x.x see http://docs. … for more details.")
   // you could also implement some functionality that logs that to your server
   this._private_A();
 },

 b() { this._private_A(); },

 c() { this._private_A(); }

}
```

Ideally, you would create some helper function for that so that you won't need to repeat yourself over and over again.

A module that was (I'm not sure if it is) commonly used was [depd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/depd).

`depd` ensures that the logging is only done one the first call of the function, which prevents pollution of the logs.

But you don't need to use a module and you can easily reimplement its functionality yourself.

This gives you the flexibility to deprecate everything that might be problematic in your API, and gives the one using your API the feedback needed to update their code.

Doing a deprecation that way also allows you figure out if there are places in your code that still uses that deprecated function. And can make code/API rewrite easier.

`Proxy` is another way to target that problem but that requires the code where it runs on to support proxies which could be a problem (see https://caniuse.com/?search=proxy)

You would wrap object in a `Proxy` and provide that to the public:

```
const obj = {
 a() { console.log('a')},

 b() { this.a(); },

 c() { this.a(); }

}

const handler = {
  get: function (target, prop, receiver) {
    console.log(prop+' was requested')
    // do some checks
    
    // do the original call.
    return Reflect.get(...arguments);
  },
};


const proxy2 = new Proxy(obj, handler);

proxy2.a()
```

Comment: Proxy looks like a good way for my usecase! Thanks!

Comment: @KushagraGour `Proxy` cannot be used for every use-case and can also be problematic. I personally would use my first approach because you should be able to use it in all situations. But in the end it is up to you what you think is the best approach. And you can combine it with the `let stack = (new Error()).stack.split('\n').slice(2)` [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68737634/1960455) suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Redesign your object like this:

```
class A {

    publicMethod() {
        this._privateWorker()
    }

    _privateMethod() {
        this._privateWorker()
    }
    
    _privateWorker() {
        ...
    }
}
```

and make it a rule that private (underscore) methods are only allowed to call other private methods, never a public one.

To answer the question as asked, you can inspect the stack and treat the call as internal if the stack starts with your class name:

```js
class MyClass {
    a() {
        let stack = (new Error()).stack.split('\n').slice(2)
        if (stack[0].includes('MyClass.'))
            console.log('internal call')
        else
            console.log('external call')
    }

    b() {
        this.a()
    }

    c() {
        this.a();
    }

}

obj = new MyClass;
obj.c();
obj.a();
```